# PostgreSQL: how to insert null value to uuid

Tags: postgresql, null, sql-insert

Need to insert null value to field with `uuid` type without **NOT NULL** specification (not primary key).

When I try insert '', this return:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for uuid: ""
```

When I try insert null, this return:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "uuid" violates not-null constraint
```

How to do it?

psql 9.3.5

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO inv_location (address_id)
VALUES (null)
```

Comment: Please provide your table definition (what you get with `\d tbl` in `psql`). And also the verbatim `INSERT` command you are using. And *always* your version of Postgres.

Comment: You should leave the table definition in the question. It's the key to the answer (and should be part of any such question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the column is defined `NOT NULL`, you **cannot** enter a `NULL` value. Period.

In this error message:

> ERROR:  null value in column "uuid" violates not-null constraint

"uuid" is the ***name*** of the column, not the ***data type*** of `address_id`. And this column is defined `NOT NULL`:

```
uuid         | character varying(36) | not null
```

Your `INSERT` statement does not include "uuid" in the target list, so NULL is defaults to NULL in absence of a different column default. Boom.

Goes to show how basic type names (ab)used as identifier lead to confusing error messages.

Comment: @user4265223: Turns out it is defined NOT NULL after all.

Answer (score 9):

In Postgres use `uuid_nil()` function to simulate empty uuid (same as `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`)

```
INSERT INTO inv_location (address_id)
VALUES (uuid_nil())
```

You might need to have uuid extension (not sure), if you do, run this (only once):

```
create extension if not exists "uuid-ossp";
```

Comment: In my use case I'm not able to easily install the extension and I've thought minutes and minutes about how to do so. 
I'm not a smart person. Thank you anyways, I'll just copy the string :-)

Answer (score 3):

INSERT INTO inv_location (address_id)
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::UUID)